# Opengl rendering in server

Tags: opengl, video, 3d, server, gpu

I'm trying to render 3D model on a dedicated server (which obviously doesn't have any screen). Until now my different attempt (using blender) led me to the conclusion that CPU rendering is far too long for what i want.
My scene is very simple, only a textured sphere and a camera turning around to record it. The quality of the Opengl render in the blender's viewport is far enough for what i want. I have the opportunity to switch to a GPU server ( with additional costs ).

So my questions are, is it possible to use openGL to render a video on a server that doesn't have a screen nor a Xorg server ?
If that's the case, which technology should I look for ? Does the rendering time will be as fast as in a classic openGL program (or at least generate 25 frames per seconds) ? During my research I heard about mesa3D and EGL, but as a novice I don't know if I should continue looking that way.

Comment: You might want to check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046855/in-linux-do-i-need-an-x-server-to-do-off-screen-rendering) (and especially the last link in the comments below the accepted answer).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking: Part of your question is "Can I write an OpenGL program that runs without an X-server". But then you refer to blender. The answer might strongly depend on whether you want to run a existing program (where you can't modify the way the context is created) or write your own application.

Comment: @BDL I used blender in a first time, but the rendering time was too long. So now the goal is to write my own application and I thought about openGL. The problem is that it must be executed on a dedicated server without any screen.